# Refresh flex spark theme

Tags: apache-flex, flex-spark

I have two flex projects: A project with my custom theme and another project in which I want to use my custom theme. However, every time I modify the theme, I have to import it again, clean and refresh the project. I am using Flash Builder 4.5. Does anybody know a better way to use the custom themes?

Comment: Did you create a SWC theme or a CSS theme?  I'm not sure what you mean by "importing" a theme.  You are importing it into what?  And how?

Comment: I create a SWC theme, and I import the theme to a project through properties-Flex Theme- Import Theme, that makes the project work with my custom theme

Comment: Try adding the theme to the project as a compiler setting.  -theme="pathToMyTheme" on the Flex Compiler tab.  You'll still have to recompile the app every time the theme changes, but at least you won't have to import it.

Comment: It's giving me errors with spark skins that I haven't customized.

Comment: It's giving you errors or warnings?  You may have to include both skins using the compiler argument.  I use these arguments to add the mobile and spark theme to a web project. Note the += for the second value: -theme="C:\Users\jhouser\Documents\career\clients\ActiveClients\DotComIt\Development\Flexsdks\flex_sdk_4.5.0.20967A\frameworks\themes\Mobile\mobile.swc" -theme+="C:\Users\jhouser\Documents\career\clients\ActiveClients\DotComIt\Development\Flexsdks\flex_sdk_4.5.0.20967A\frameworks\themes\Spark\spark.css"

Comment: I'm pretty sure the first theme listed will take precedence; and you'll have to specify the skin class on every component that needs to use the other theme.  It can be tedious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution to the problem. It is not that difficult and the results are great; you will be able to edit the theme, go to the design view of the project using the theme and see the results (no imports, no cleans, no refreshes).

Steps:

1. Open both projects at the same time in Flash Builder
2. In the main project (the project using the theme), go to *Project > Properties > Flex Build Path*
3. Select the *Library Path* tab and click *Add Project*
4. Select the project containing the theme
5. You're done! The main project will now depend on the theme and will recompile the theme every time you build.

Hope it helps!